# ASP.NET Core querystring object

Tags: c#, forms, get, query-string

I have a method called in get that receive in input (from the query string) some parameters that represent an object:

```
public override async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery]MyFilter filter) 
{
    ...
}

public class MyFilter : BaseFilter
{           
   public List<string> Rules{ get; set; } = new List<string>();            
   public string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

If I call my method with this query string the property `Rules` is empty:

```
?filter.SearchString=&filter.Rules[]=foo&filter.Rules[]=bar
```

but if I call it with this query string, the property `Rules` is filled correctly:

```
?filter.SearchString=&filter.Rules[0]=foo&filter.Rules[1]=bar
```

So the field "Role"s is a html select so when user fill this field I do not know indexes.

Does someone have the same problem (and a solution for it)?

Comment: I assume by "Roles" in the last line, you mean "Rules"?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Just the bit with the form (if there is one) and the HTML select.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use:

```
?SearchString=&Rules[]=foo&Rules[]=bar
```